# modifyMVar: where does it allow another writer to "enter"?

Tags: haskell

This is the code of `modifyMVar_`. The comment says it allows multiple writers. And that it replaces the original content if an exception happens. I am not 100% sure about my understanding where it happens looking at the code.

1. **where does it allow another writer to alter the content?** I see only one possibility: if `putMVar` is not atomic (obviously it is not) and another thread puts its own content faster. Is it the place?
2. **where does it replace the original content on exception**? I see that `restore` returns taken `a` value back. Do they mean again possibility of multiple writers during `putMVar` but now in the "exception handler"?
3. **Can I use `modifyMVar` as a synchronized code block**? Like a mutex in Java or in Python? It seems yes, but what could be a problem in comparison with a standard lock/mutex in other languages? I think the `io` argument is executed mutually exclusive as in a standard lock, is not it?

```hs
{-|
  An exception-safe wrapper for modifying the contents of an 'MVar'.
  Like 'withMVar', 'modifyMVar' will replace the original contents of
  the 'MVar' if an exception is raised during the operation.  This
  function is only atomic if there are no other producers for this
  'MVar'. In other words, it cannot guarantee that, by the time
  'modifyMVar_' gets the chance to write to the MVar, the value
  of the MVar has not been altered by a write operation from another thread.
-}
{-# INLINE modifyMVar_ #-}
modifyMVar_ :: MVar a -> (a -> IO a) -> IO ()
modifyMVar_ m io =
  mask $ \restore -> do
    a  <- takeMVar m
    a' <- restore (io a) `onException` putMVar m a
    putMVar m a'
```

Comment: Have you read the [module documentation for MVar](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html)? It explains what an MVar is and how it behaves. It also clarifies that the other functions in this module are just a composition of take + put wrapped with errer handling. Knowing that is much more useful than reading the documentation for a specific function, and I think answers all of your questions.

Comment: TBH the 2nd item is not obvious from the module documentation and the code. The 1st item is only my understanding, but I will be happy if somebody tells me: yes, right (or no, wrong). Also the module documentation contains vogue wording like " susceptible to race conditions, deadlocks or uncaught exceptions" - I don't see it from the code of the module though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. where does it allow another writer to alter the content?

I assume you are referring to this part of the documentation:

> This function is only atomic if there are no other producers for this `MVar`.

The idea behind `modifyMVar_` is that if there are multiple concurrent `modifyMVar_`, one of them will run its `takeMVar`, and now the `MVar` is empty so all the other `modifyMVar_` will block on `takeMVar`. This guarantees that `modifyMVar_` (on the same variable) will run sequentially, and therefore atomically.

If another thread uses `putMVar` directly (instead of indirectly via `modifyMVar_`), that will unlock a waiting `modifyMVar_`, which breaks the atomicity guarantee.

> 2. where does it replace the original content on exception?

`` action `onException` putMVar m a `` runs `action` and if it raises an exceptions, runs `putMVar m a` before re-raising the exception.

> 3. Can I use modifyMVar as a synchronized code block?

Yes, an `MVar ()` is a mutex.

Comment: Well, I got you, except 2. The documentation: `'modifyMVar' will replace the original contents of the 'MVar' if an exception is raised during the operation.` but I see that if an exception is raised it calls `putMVar m a` where `a` is the original content of the M-var.

Comment: @RandomB: That wording is a little confusing. It uses “replace” in the sense of “restore” or “put back”.